# Get selected DropDownList item from MVC Partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I use @Html.DropDownList in a partial view for show the list of banks and render it in the Bank Branch view.
How can i get the selected Bank in @Html.DropDownList and fill the BankId in the BankBranchModel .

here is my code:

BankBranchModel :

```
public class BankBranchModel : BaseModel
{
    public int? **BankID** { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

My partial view :

```
@Html.DropDownList("Banks", Model , "- Please Select -"})
```

BankBranch View:

```
@model MvcFirstSample.Models.BankBranchModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "create";
}

<h2>create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <div class="editor-field">
        **@Html.Action("GetAllBank", "BankBranch")**

    </div>
```

GetAllBanks for return the Partial view:

```
public ActionResult GetAllBank()
        {

            var Banks = Context.Banks.ToList();
            List<BankLookup> BankLookupList = new List<BankLookup>();

            var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var Bank in Banks)
            {
                listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = Bank.Name, Value = Bank.Id.ToString()});
            }

            **return PartialView("BankLookup", listItems);**
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't want to use `ViewBag`?
In your  `Partial View` you can say:

```
@Html.DropDownList("listItems",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listItems )
```

, then use `Jquery` to get selected item:

```
      var selectBanks= $("#listItems");

        var selectedOptionId = selectBanks.find("option:selected").val();
```

Then populate input for bankid assuming it has id of bankid:

```
     $("#bankid").val(selectedOptionId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way...

In your Partial View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("bank_list")
```

In your controller, populate the list by binding ids and values:

```
ViewBag.bank_list = new SelectList(listItems, "Text", "Value");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I dont want to use viewBag.

Comment: If that is the case, you may want to consider JQuery/Javascript. It is a bit more involved so you should research it some more.